# Filtering rows in pandas with conditions over multiple (> 100) columns

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with 20K columns and I'd need to filter specific rows by applying a condition over 400 columns:

```
        COL1  COL2 ... COL400 total
  0      1.0  5.0      3.0    1.21
  1      1.0  NaN      NaN    4.33
  2      NaN  NaN      NaN    1.00
  3      NaN  2.0      1.0    0.12
  4      NaN  NaN      NaN    0.00
  5      1.0  3.0      4.0    3.39
  ...
```

The need I have is keeping the rows containing **at least** 1 numeric value between [1, 5] in at least one of these 400 columns:

```
        COL1  COL2 ... COL400 total
  0      1.0  5.0      3.0    1.21
  1      1.0  NaN      NaN    4.33
  3      NaN  2.0      1.0    0.12
  5      1.0  3.0      4.0    3.39
  ...
```

Please note that there is an extra column total, which **should not be included in this filtering** (as the name implies, after applying the filtering we add up the totals of all the remaining rows)

So far the naïve approach I've been using for less columns has been using something like this:

```
df[df.eval('COL1 >= 1 & COL1 <= 5 | COL2 >= 1 & COL2 <= 5')]
```

But when dealing with hundreds of columns this becomes impractical (and requires a lot of typing as well!)

I'm wondering what is the right approach to use here. I've started adding more conditions to the above expression but when reaching to 30 columns I start getting stack overflows or just memory errors.

I've also tried using other "tricks" such as re-writing the expression like:

```
df[df.eval('~(COL1 != COL1 & COL2 != COL2)')]
```

but again this doesn't help.

Also ideally, I'd like to use a simple way to define a boolean expression in a string if possible, as the idea would be allowing end-users to define custom expressions for this filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare all columns and check if at least one `True` per row by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
#check values in all columns
df = df[((df >= 1) & (df <= 5)).any(axis=1)]
#check values in columns specified in list
#cols = ['COL1','COL2', ...]
#df = df[((df[cols] >= 1) & (df[cols] <= 5)).any(axis=1)]

print (df)
   COL1  COL2  COL400
0   1.0   5.0     3.0
1   1.0   NaN     NaN
3   NaN   2.0     1.0
5   1.0   3.0     4.0
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising. I have two follow-up questions: 1. If I also had an extra column which is later needed but shouldn't be included in the filtering, is there any way to do so? 2. Is there any equivalent way to use a string as input, so this could be used by end-users?

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw - There is only one column need exclude?

Comment: Yes, at least the current requirement is just one

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw - Is possible change data in question by edit for this new requirements?

Comment: Absolutely. Just did so, and apologies for not having included them in the first place.

Comment: Use `df = df[((df.drop('total', axis=1) >= 1) & (df.drop('total', axis=1) <= 5)).any(axis=1)]`

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw - Or if need all columns without last `df = df[((df.iloc[:, :-1] >= 1) & (df.iloc[:, :-1] <= 5)).any(axis=1)]`